# React not sending to correct URL

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, parameters

I am working with Node.JS in backend and React in frontend.
I deployed my API to API gateway on AWS through lambda function using serverless.
I am trying to get a URL with params in it.
The URL is working properly in Postman but when i try fetching/sending URL from React its not working.
Here are my two react functions.

```
const updateReview = (movie) => {
Axios.put(url,null, {
  params:{
  movieName: movie,
  movieReview: newReview
}
});
setNewReview("");
window.location.reload();
};

const deleteReview = (movie) => {
Axios.delete(url,null, {
  params:{
  movieName: movie
}
});
window.location.reload();
};
```

Here, the 'movie' value is being passed from a onSubmit actions from Update and Delete button.

The URL for update as used from Postman is this:
url?movieName=aa&movieReview=ok

Note: Here url is the URL which API gateway has generated.
Everything is working fine from Postman but not from React.
This means there is no error from API gateway as well as Node backend.